Smoothest logpdf distribution
I want to solve the following optimization
$$\min_{f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log(f(x)))^2 dx$$
subject to the constraint that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = 1 $$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)dx = 0$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2f(x)dx = 1 $$
In another words, $f$ is a pdf of a random variable with expected value of 0, variance of 1, and maximizes the "smoothness" of the logpdf.
I tried to solve this with Euler Lagrange equation, but the differential equation seemed intractable.

Does $f$ need to be $C^2$? If not, maybe explore Laplace distributions.

I would guess it would be C2, but I just need the second derivative to be defined.

I imagine $C^2$ approximations will be arbitrarily close to $\exp(-\sqrt{2}\vert x\vert)/\sqrt{2}$, though I could be wrong.

Does $\log$ mean natural log? Also, perhaps use $\inf$ not $\min$ since the minimum might not exist (the interval $(0,1]$ has no minimum but has infimum $0$).

@rural reader I think your function has infinite value due to the discontinuity. It doesn’t vanish if you look at a limit of functions that converges uniformly.

@Lucenaposition you can assume natural log. Note that changing the base doesn’t change the problem because it just scales the integral. Yes. I agree that inf will be better. I was hoping for a closed form of the function. Do you think it doesn’t exist?

The differential equation looks a bit better if you work with $f(x) = \exp(-\Phi(x))$. There you get some sort of higher order Bratu-looking problem. I doubt this is tractable though

@whpowell96 I have tried that as well, and by solving for the Euler Lagrange equation, it becomes a very difficult 4th order differential equation.

With the centered Laplace distribution, the integrand of the objective function is zero everywhere except at a single point, the origin, where it’s undefined. But yep, that $f$ is not $C^2$.

Even if you work in Sobolev spaces, the Laplace example still doesn't work because integral is $\delta(x)^2$

@whpowell96: Is there reason to think there’s any sort of delta-functioney stuff going on?

Since the resulting integral is infinite, no. This simply shows that $C^2$ approximations of a Laplace density are not optimal since the resulting functional values are unbounded

It suggests, that’s all, that a $C^2$ doesn’t exist.

$C^2$ solutions may exist, they just won't be along a sequence approaching a Laplace density is all I'm saying

I suspect one can show existence of solutions to the 4th order nonlinear PDE for the log of the density but I highly doubt a closed form solution exists without many more simplifying assumptions

@whpowell96: I look forward to being shown wrong about the problem as stated. Existence in $C^2(R)$ will more than satisfy me.

How about the continuous uniform distribution over $[-6,6]$? Am I missing something?
